# Translate postgis data to a coordinate system

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I have a PostGIS database where the data is in an unknown or incorrect coordinate system.  Is there a way given some known points in the data to translate all the data to a specific coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [short blog post](http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections/2017/01/06/finding-a-projection.html) and some [java code](https://gitlab.com/snippets/34902) to solve this problem last week (and the [pom](https://gitlab.com/snippets/35169) to build it).

Answer (score 1):

If it is just in an unknown co-ordinate system, but you know the EPSG code that is should be. You can run:

```
ST_SetSRID(geom,EPSG_code)
```

For example I have a table called *lines*, which has a geometry column called *geom*, which I want to set to EPSG:4326:

```
ALTER TABLE lines
ALTER geom TYPE geometry(LineString, 4326) USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326)
```

Comment: I dont know the EPSG code.

Comment: If you know the general area, you can try: http://projfinder.com/